# Six "workers" assigned when maxsize set to 3

Tags: python, gevent, python-multithreading

I am reading the documentations for the gevent framework and I am confused about how the workers are assigned.

Why are six workers assigned tasks in the first loop, when I have set the maxsize to 3?

```
import gevent
from gevent.queue import Queue, Empty
tasks = Queue(maxsize=3)
def worker(n):
    try:
        while True:
            task = tasks.get(timeout=1) # decrements queue size by 1
            print('Worker %s got task %s' % (n, task))
            gevent.sleep(0)
    except Empty:
        print('Quitting time!')

def boss():
    """
    Boss will wait to hand out work until a individual worker is
    free since the maxsize of the task queue is 3.
    """

    for i in xrange(1,10):
        tasks.put(i)
    print('Assigned all work in iteration 1')

    for i in xrange(10,20):
        tasks.put(i)
    print('Assigned all work in iteration 2')

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(boss),
    gevent.spawn(worker, 'steve'),
    gevent.spawn(worker, 'john'),
    gevent.spawn(worker, 'bob'),
])
```

This is the output when I run the code:

```
Worker steve got task 1
Worker john got task 2
Worker bob got task 3
Worker steve got task 4
Worker bob got task 5
Worker john got task 6
Assigned all work in iteration 1
Worker steve got task 7
Worker john got task 8
Worker bob got task 9
Worker steve got task 10
Worker bob got task 11
Worker john got task 12
Worker steve got task 13
Worker john got task 14
Worker bob got task 15
Worker steve got task 16
Worker bob got task 17
Worker john got task 18
Assigned all work in iteration 2
Worker steve got task 19
Quitting time!
Quitting time!
Quitting time!
```

Answer (score 2):

If the queue is filled, future calls to `put` will block until there is space. So the first three tasks get added to the queue, and then the fourth call to `put` will block until one of the workers has dequeued a task so there's room. It's not six tasks being enqueued; it's ten. The fact that "Assigned all work in iteration 1" appears after six tasks is purely coincidental, and may change from run to run. All tasks in iteration 1 have been added to the queue by the time the boss thread prints that message; but not all of them have been fully handled by workers.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to post a answer in my question,Since i have read the previous answer and it seems not solve my question,Then i try to modify the program and look the output of the new program, I found the reason
why there are always six workers get task before print "Assigned all work in iteration 1" is Only if the sixth worker get a task from the queue(for the time being,the queue is 6,7,8),the ninth task is allowed to put in the queue,then the iteration 1 is fininshed and print.It is not purely coincidental.it will print the (9-maxsize) tasks before iteration 1 ends.check output if the program below,it is quite explaining.

```
import gevent
from gevent.queue import Queue, Empty
tasks = Queue(maxsize=3)
def worker(n):
    try:
        while True:
            task = tasks.get(timeout=1) # decrements queue size by 1
            print('Worker %s got task %s' % (n, task))
            gevent.sleep(3*task)
    except Empty:
        print('Quitting time!')

def boss():
    """
    Boss will wait to hand out work until a individual worker is
    free since the maxsize of the task queue is 3.
    """

    for i in xrange(1,10):
        tasks.put(i)
        print "puting task %d ok" % i
    print('Assigned all work in iteration 1')

    for i in xrange(10,20):
        tasks.put(i)
    print('Assigned all work in iteration 2')

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(boss),
    gevent.spawn(worker, 'steve'),
    gevent.spawn(worker, 'john'),
    gevent.spawn(worker, 'bob'),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is for each iteration to handout only three tasks, try explicitly coding it that way, ie.

```
for i in xrange(1,3):
```

instead of using the queue size to try and control it - that, as Sneftel may be getting at, is not the purpose of 'maxsize'.  'maxsize' controls the number of items in the queue at a given time - it will accept new items, once finished tasks come out of the queue.

You say "# decrements queue size by 1" but it doesn't really, it just pulls the next task out of the size-3 queue, making room for another task to be added.